# Is there any way to get last fetched id using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to get a bulk of data from my database, but I got **memory out** error so I'm trying to divide my returned data into spices each one has only 500 rows. I'm doing this by making a recursion function using **PDO** and **PHP** but I need to get *last fetched id* each time I call the function. so I'm asking is there any way to get the last fetched id using **PDO** the function will be like this

```
$names = array();
function getData(&names){
   $db->query("SELECT id, colName FROM tableName WHERE id between last-fetched-id AND last-fetched-id + 500");
   $get = $db->fetchAll();
   if(!empty($get)){
      foreach($get AS $row){
        array_push($names,$row['colName']);
      }
      getData();
   }
}
```

So could any one please tell me how to get the **last-fetched-id**

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need all the names from he table? What are you going to do with them?

Comment: Try the SQL LIMIT and OFFSET clauses?

Comment: @Your Common Sense It is just an example not the real query

Comment: @Robert Using LIMIT and OFFSET clauses also getting **memory out** error

Comment: This error is **solely** from your terrible solution for a non existent problem. Now go tell us what does your query do and what you are running it for.

Comment: Can't you save the last_fetched_id in a php variable?

Comment: I'll have to agree with @Your Common Sense here... if you want to store all data from the table in memory (that `$names` array), it won't matter if you try to load in one big fetch or several small ones. So it boils down to: what do you really want to do?

Answer (score 1):

There are too many errors in your code, it's impossible to fix the one by one. So here is just a code you need.

```
function getData(){
    return $db->query("SELECT colName FROM tableName")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}
```